# How to compute a special form of Betweenness Centrality in python

Tags: python, networkx

First, I use NetworkX to represent graphs in python. Second, [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html) is the predefined Betweenness centrality in NetworkX. The problem is, we defined the Betweenness Centrality without the denominator. So, c_B(v) is just the sum over all shortes paths they go through the vertex v. Is there a way to modify the predefined Betweenness centrality, such that I get "our" definition of Betweenness centrality? I tried already the [load_centrality](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.load_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.load_centrality), but this does not fit too.

Best regards,
Matthias

Comment: Is your graph connected?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes my graph is connected and also undirected.

Comment: Just multiply the betweeness centrality by `len(g.all_shortest_paths())` to undo the normalisation.

Comment: Also, why does `load_centrality` not fit your use-case?

Comment: Hello Paul, I don't know why it does not work. I only know, that the load_centrality-Values are diffrent to mine. Further, the describtion is a bit confused. They say:
"The load centrality of a node is the fraction of all shortest paths that pass through that node."
I do not see here a fraction. I think, they forgot the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to obtain your *betweenness centrality* from the original function (at least not to me). One easy way to obtain it is by implementing a function yourself. Look below for an example. The example would only be efficient if your graph is not too big (the calculation  takes ~ 9 seconds for a graph with 120 vertices).

```
import networkx as nx

def bc(G):
    vertices = G.nodes()
    new_bc = {}
    paths = defaultdict(dict)

    # Get shortest paths between all pairs of vertices
    for i, vertex in enumerate(vertices[:-1]):
        for o_vertex in vertices[i+1:]:
            paths[vertex][o_vertex] = [path for path in
                                       nx.all_shortest_paths(G, vertex, o_vertex)]

    for vertex in vertices:
        counter = 0
        for i, vertex1 in enumerate(vertices[:-1]):
            for vertex2 in vertices[i+1:]:
                for path in paths[vertex1][vertex2]:
                    if vertex in path[1:-1]:
                        counter += 1
        new_bc[vertex] = counter

    return new_bc
```

Where `bc[node]` if the number of shortest paths in `G` passing through `node`.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me :)
Moreover, the graphs are not huge. It's just to verify my own (pen and paper) calculations.